# Interface builder had different items in the objecs library?

Tags: xcode, ios7, interface-builder

This morning I came back to my Xcode 5.1.1 project after a few days away. I switched to the (already open) Interface Builder window. Just as I was clicking on the object I wanted to change, I happened to notice in the lower right that the Objects Library showed a list of items I hadn't seen before. I was already clicking the mouse button, and in the brief moment before the click took effect, I noticed objects for disclosure buttons, beveled buttons, and a few other button shapes that aren't normally there.

Of course, then the mouse click took effect, selected the object I was intending to edit, and the objects library changed back to the usual array of views, labels, buttons, etc. I didn't manage to see what was actually selected prior to clicking the mouse.

I've been searching for the objects library, but haven't found anything that explains the list of items I was looking at. I assume it must be options specific to some element in my UI, but I've tried clicking through all my elements, including a table, but can't find that same list of objects.

What am I missing out on?

Comment: Sounds like you saw the object set for Mac OSX Development - IB seems to like to load it as default

Comment: @Jugale: ah, that makes sense. Want to post as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The objects you were seeing belong to the MacOSX development set - it seems that InterfaceBuilder loads them first and waits until later to load iOS ones if required.